# How can I solve CondaHTTPError in anaconda?

Tags: python

I'm using Windows 10 pro(x64) and I have just installed Anaonda 4.3.1

But whenever I try to install a package or update conda, it shows an error like the below.

```
(d:\Miniconda3) C:\Windows\system32>conda update conda
Fetching package metadata .....

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <None>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert bad record mac')],)",),),)
```

*conda config --set ssl_verify False* doesn't make any difference either.

I have no problem installing packages using pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors coming from such abstracting (i.e. with a high level of abstraction) tools are usually really hard to debug from the tool themselves (it requires quite a lot of digging around in the tool's code to pinpoint and finally find the issue); to the extent that in the vast majority of cases, once you've debugged it, you know enough about the tool in question to actually be able to write a patch to solve that problem.

What I would recommend is to first trace how does `conda` get the metadata it is getting at first (first line of your output). On UNIX I would recommend [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump), but on windows I would use [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) (albeit according to [the wikipedia page for tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump), it works on windows too).

Once you know what host the package should be obtained from, you can try to understand why it occurs. Namely, the [`bad record mac` error should not occur under normal conditions](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/39846/82196); i.e. either you have a network problem (try with another network) or there is a server (more likely if `conda` used to work) or client problem.

To try to debug the SSL issue once you know the host, run:

```
openssl s_client -connect $host:443 -msg -debug
```

Where `$host` is the host you found using tcpdump/wireshark.

Best of luck!

*Note: I have not linked wireshark.org in this answer, but instead the wikipedia page for wireshark to prevent supporting bogus security practices <sup>[1](https://www.troyhunt.com/cloudflare-ssl-and-unhealthy-security-absolutism/),[2](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/07/14/cloudflare-we-have-a-problem/)</sup>. Please do not edit that link.*